# Please merge tag "digital" into "digital-photography" (or the other way around)

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-naming

We don't need both [digital](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital) and [digital-photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-photography). Let's kill one of them, please. Since the first is on 32 questions and the second on 310, I guess [digital](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital) should go — although I think the -photography postfix is kind of superfluous on a *photography* site.

There's also [film](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film) and [film-photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film-photography) — but here, the former is much, much more popular rather than the other way around, yet weirdly I can see at least some possible use here, since "film" is actually a *thing* and film-photography an action or practice, while we have more specific tags like [sensor](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensor) for digital.

Comment: I made the digital-photography merge into digital, I think the "photography" is redundant in this scenario. I left film alone though, I share your sense that there may be some use for the distinction, at least for now.

Comment: JoanneC: Thanks!